# access the values ​of this result, obtained from an api

Tags: python, django, api, request, token

GOOD, I have a problem, I am developing an application that consumes an api and returns the token, but obviously that token expires, I wanted to know some way to get the value of the access-toke, the truth is I don't know if this result is a json or simply a dictionary, disuclpar I am something newbie is this of programming, the thing is that I cannot access that value to store it in a variable because when the token expires, I have to raise everything again and paste the new generated token, all this is being developed with the request library and for the django backend

```
class Token(object):
    def __init__(self, url, payload):
        self.url = url

        self.payload = payload
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

        self.response = requests.request("POST", self.url, headers=headers, data=self.payload)

        if self.response.status_code == 200:
            print('Success!')
        elif self.response.status_code == 404:
            print('Not Found.')

        a = self.response.text
        print (a)


    def consulter_padron(self):
        url = "I delete this, they kick me out of work hahaha"


        payload={} 
        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjVMcDByZ0xrNmJYS3RHZURzSmhMeS1xakFobyIsImtpZCI6IjVMcDByZ0xrNmJYS3RHZURzSmhMeS1xakFobyJ9.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.CbYFfMNHfaqjmtdDx6Bb3sfrzMBbWmi9p1-4xsYLQxOmigupwZqnHHopy5Ltu3mwWftNwvPj0Lx1bH5m1kI0wG0Y_zWqQ3N7UacZDtApfaoNpwOjygPWcZsHj83V2xdYKSPGBFjaDng_9TECBz4ANOlmbh7c0pklLu-nA_Od9E_wa2znq8CGv4sxIC4ViTeoEclMAq--sP2j1FNxZiFinq7dG32QV7zzR_1JJjVjtzK4eAT4CViZFhedsswn9OEn6wctJtmnDkRBnQioHSvz2wM5J-tngVS6tn_o1PUwVtykBc_0_TTfowiJkAkEmSQJKobAQPIgVvPrH4JsNeahGw'
        }

        self.response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

        print (self.response.text)


        

prueba01 = Token('I delete this, they kick me out of work hahaha')
prueba01.consulter_padron()
```

Comment: having a problem can be good however most people associate it with something bad ,sooo? anyhow. how do You get the token? do You copy it from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can check whether your token is expired or not using [pyjwt](https://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/) module for example:

```
import jwt
import time

key = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjVMcDByZ0xrNmJYS3RHZURzSmhMeS1xakFobyIsImtpZCI6IjVMcDByZ0xrNmJYS3RHZURzSmhMeS1xakFobyJ9.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.CbYFfMNHfaqjmtdDx6Bb3sfrzMBbWmi9p1-4xsYLQxOmigupwZqnHHopy5Ltu3mwWftNwvPj0Lx1bH5m1kI0wG0Y_zWqQ3N7UacZDtApfaoNpwOjygPWcZsHj83V2xdYKSPGBFjaDng_9TECBz4ANOlmbh7c0pklLu-nA_Od9E_wa2znq8CGv4sxIC4ViTeoEclMAq--sP2j1FNxZiFinq7dG32QV7zzR_1JJjVjtzK4eAT4CViZFhedsswn9OEn6wctJtmnDkRBnQioHSvz2wM5J-tngVS6tn_o1PUwVtykBc_0_TTfowiJkAkEmSQJKobAQPIgVvPrH4JsNeahGw'
decoded = jwt.decode(key, options={"verify_signature": False})
exp_timestamp = decoded['exp']

print(f'expires: {time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(exp_timestamp))}')
print(f'expired: {exp_timestamp < time.time()}')
```

```
expires: Thu, 01 Apr 2021 11:50:58
expired: True
```

Not sure if it answers your question though :)

Comment: the thing would be like putting the token in a variable and passing it in the headers, which I can't do

Comment: if `a` is a variable for a token in your code - you can use f-string to pass it in headers, like:

`a = self.response.text; headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {a}'}`

Again, if that's not a question - let me know :)

Comment: Thank you, the problem was that I was passing the token already with the "", I solved it, thank you very much